# Can the Banach-Tarski Paradox be extended to an arbitrary number of duplications?

Tags: geometry, analysis

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55616/is-there-a-free-subgroup-of-rank-3-in-so-3), I recently asked if there were free subgroups of rank 3 or higher of the group of rotations in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  From the answers, it follows that any free subgroup of rank 2 admits subgroups of arbitrary countable rank.

My question now is whether this can be used to extend the Banach-Tarski Paradox to show that the sphere cannot only be duplicated (leveraging the subgroup of rotations of rank 2), but may be done in a way to produce $n$ copies using a finite number of disjoint subsets of the original unit sphere (leveraging a subgroup of rotations of rank $n$).  All I have seen in this vein is re-applying the original statement $n$ times in order to create $n$ spheres, but it seems they could be created all at once using a free subgroup of rank $n$, correct?

Comment: Not in a trivial way.  Why not carry it out yourself to see if it works?

Comment: Great to know!!  Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is answered in the affirmative in Chapter 6 of Stan Wagon's book on the Banach-Tarski Paradox, "Free Groups of Large Rank: Getting a Continuum of Spheres from One."

Using the free subgroups of rank $n$ (of a free group of rank 2), one can extend BT to $n$ copies at once.

Furthermore, as stated in the comments of the above-referenced question, one can use the fact that a free group of rank 2 has a subgroup of countably infinite rank to produce a countably infinite number of copies of the original sphere.

Moreover, it is possible to produce copies of the ball with cardinality of the continuum, though I do not understand the development presented in the text well enough to summarize here.

Comment: Wagon's book is excellent.  It is very clearly written.

Comment: @Ross - Agreed.  I'm looking forward to digging into Chs. 4-6 to really see what is happening here.

Comment: Hi Rachel! This is just to make sure you saw this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56825/reference-about-the-banach-tarski-paradox), and this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56825/reference-about-the-banach-tarski-paradox/56843#56843), and who wrote it.

Comment: @Pierre, thank you!  The link you reference is precisely the talk I gave at MathFest in Kentucky last week, using Stan Wagon's book as a guide (though I only looked at chapters 1-3).  The motivation for my question above was from a question posed tome by another student, asking why it only deals with 2 balls at the final state, which prompted me to think about methods of extending this.