# The free group on 3 generators is isomorphic to a subgroup of the free group on 2 generators.

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a free subgroup of rank 3 in $SO_3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55616/is-there-a-free-subgroup-of-rank-3-in-so-3)

How is this possible?

Here are some facts:

1. $F_2 \subset F_3$
2. $F_2 \not\cong F_3$

Fact 2 implies that $F_3$ is isomorphic to a proper subgroup of $F_2$, i.e. one in which there are exist some relations between the generators of $F_2$.

But I'm really struggling to come up with anything else.

Comment: Does it help if I mention that $F_2$ in fact contains a subgroup isomorphic to the free group on $\aleph_0$ generators? Use the universal property of $F_3$ to show that you can construct a suitable homomorphism $F_3 \to F_2$, and then use the characterisation of $F_2$ in terms of words to show that the homomorphism is injective.

Comment: In fact $F_2$ contains the free group on countably many generators. See the linked question. It is not true that there exist any relations between the generators of $F_2$ in a proper subgroup of $F_2$, and I don't really understand how this could be (since $F_2$ is, by definition, free). Perhaps you are confusing subgroups with quotient groups.